# Define a name to exported excel file in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I'm looking to define a name to exported excel file in JQuery. Say every time I export the table data the name default displays in tableExport.xls format. Here I want to define a name to exported file say as testfile.xls. help me out with the issue.

```
$(function() {
        var $result = $('#eventsResult');

        $('#eventsTable').on('all.bs.table', function(e, name, args) {
            console.log('Event:', name, ', data:', args);
        }).on('click-row.bs.table', function(e, row, $element) {
            $result.text('Event: click-row.bs.table');
        }).on('dbl-click-row.bs.table', function(e, row, $element) {
            $result.text('Event: dbl-click-row.bs.table');
        }).on('sort.bs.table', function(e, name, order) {
            $result.text('Event: sort.bs.table');
        }).on('check.bs.table', function(e, row) {
            $result.text('Event: check.bs.table');
        }).on('uncheck.bs.table', function(e, row) {
            $result.text('Event: uncheck.bs.table');
        }).on('check-all.bs.table', function(e) {
            $result.text('Event: check-all.bs.table');
        }).on('uncheck-all.bs.table', function(e) {
            $result.text('Event: uncheck-all.bs.table');
        }).on('load-success.bs.table', function(e, data) {
            $result.text('Event: load-success.bs.table');
        }).on('load-error.bs.table', function(e, status) {
            $result.text('Event: load-error.bs.table');
        }).on('column-switch.bs.table', function(e, field, checked) {
            $result.text('Event: column-switch.bs.table');
        }).on('page-change.bs.table', function(e, number, size) {
            $result.text('Event: page-change.bs.table');
        }).on('search.bs.table', function(e, text) {
            $result.text('Event: search.bs.table');
        });
    });

    $(function() {
        var
        $table = $('#eventsTable');
        $('#export').click(function() {
            $table.viewMPR({
                type : 'excel',
                escape : false
            });
        });
    });



<button id="export" class="btn btn-default">Export Excel</button>
```

Comment: How is Java involved?

Comment: I mean in Jquery

Comment: I removed the "Java" tag then.

Comment: Are you using a plugin / library to generate the Excel file? I could not find any reference to this `viewMPR` function